# Coordinator Address is Hard-Coded - Secure?

Tags: address-reuse, coordinator

This question might have risen out of not enough knowledge about the role of the Coordinator. But..

> Due to its one-time nature, the security of funds in an address
>   decreases rapidly if you sign multiple transactions using the same
>   key. [Iota Glossary](https://iota.readme.io/docs/glossary)

If it is not safe to use an address multiple times, is it safe to have a hard coded address for the Coordinator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coordinator uses [Merkle tree based signature scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_signature_scheme) which allows to sign multiple messages with the same public/private key pair. This Merkle tree contains 2^20 keys. That means that the coordinator is able to sign up to 1 048 576 milestones without key reuse.

To better understand how this signature sheme works look at here: https://www.imperialviolet.org/2013/07/18/hashsig.html

Comment: Thanks! Does that mean that if I want to run an Isolated Iota for myself, I have to code the coordinator myself? Or is this signature scheme also available in the open source nodes?

Comment: @MakanTayebi https://github.com/schierlm/private-iota-testnet contains a Coordinator implementation that does not sign (like on public testnet) and a Coordinator implementation that does the signing (if a non-signing coordinator would disturb your tests (e.g. performance tests) too much).

Answer (score 0):

The coordinator uses a signature scheme which allows address reuse (Winternitz + Merkle tree), so it's safe to use that address multiple times.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how the Merkle tree makes address reuse safe? It's still a Witnernitz signature like in every other transaction, so why doesn't it reveal the same amount of the private key?

Comment: Different mini-addresses are used, hashed according to the standard Merkle tree logic and the root hash is the address.